# Tkinter GUI label from a text file curly brackets

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to make a to do list in python as my first tkinter project. I'm using a text file with all of the tasks (That I added using a different program with python only, this program is for implementing the GUI to it). I am reading the file into the program as a list, and using that list as the text for a label. But when I run the program it looks great except for these annoying curly brackets. Does anyone know how to get rid of them. Thanks in advance for the help.  :)
[This is what the GUI looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMkrV.png)

[And this is the contents of the text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGWX4.png)

```
from tkinter import *
import re

window = Tk()
window.configure(bg="black")
window.title("To Do List")



#Title-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------# 

title = Label(window, text="To Do List", font=("Arial", 20, "bold"), fg = "white", bg = "black")
title.grid(column=0, row=0)

#Buttons ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

button_frame = Frame(bg = "black", highlightcolor = "white", highlightthickness=3)
button_frame.grid(row=1,column=0)

button_fonts = ("Arial",10,"bold")

add_task = Button(button_frame, text="Add Task", font=(button_fonts), fg = "white", bg = "black" )
add_task.grid(column=0, row=2)

choose_random = Button(button_frame, text="Choose a Random Task", font=(button_fonts), fg = "white", 
bg = "black" )
choose_random.grid(column=0, row=3)

delete = Button(button_frame, text="Delete", font=(button_fonts), fg = "white", bg = "black" )
delete.grid(column=0, row=4)

delete_all = Button(button_frame, text="Delete All", font=(button_fonts), fg = "white", bg = "black" )
delete_all.grid(column=0, row=5)

close = Button(button_frame, text="Close", font=(button_fonts), fg = "white", bg = "black" )
close.grid(column=0, row=6)


#Tasks ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

tasks_frame = Frame(bg = "black")
tasks_frame.grid(column=1, row=0, rowspan=2)

file = open("Python Tasks.txt","r")
counter = 0
content = file.read()
contlist = content.split("\n")

for i in contlist:
    if i:
        counter += 1
file.close()

##number = Label(window, text=("You have", counter, "uncompleted tasks"), font=(button_fonts))
##number.grid(columns=10,row=0)

file = open("Python Tasks.txt", "r")
tasks = []
for line in file:
    tasks.append(line)



print (tasks)

tasks_lbl = Label(tasks_frame, text=(tasks), font=button_fonts, bg="black", fg="white")
tasks_lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curly braces are there because you are giving tkinter a list when it expects a string. The simple solution is to convert your list to a string before using it as the text for a label.

```
tasks_lbl = Label(..., text="\n".join(tasks), ...)
```

tkinter is a thin wrapper around a tcl/tk interpreter. Tcl uses curly braces to delineate items in a list so that lists can be converted to strings and later back to a list. So, when you pass a list, it uses its own logic to convert the list to a string before adding it to the label. You want to avoid this step by explicitly converting your list before handing it off to tcl.

Here is a short program that illustrates the difference between using a list or a string with a label:

```
import tkinter as tk

data = ["one two", "three four", "five six"]

root = tk.Tk()

l1 = tk.Label(root, text=data)
l2 = tk.Label(root, text="\n".join(data))

l1.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=4, pady=4)
l2.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=4, pady=4)
```

root.mainloop()

[image: screenshot of example program]

Comment: The curly braces will only apply on items with space in the string.  So `data = ["one two", "three", "four five"]` will get `{one two} three {four five}`.

Comment: @acw1668: you're not quite correct. Braces and/or backslashes can occur for more than just spaces.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can't believe I didn't think of that. I'm still learning so thanks for reminding me.     :)